# Use Bash to send multiple SSH commands

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

This is a simple and quick question I need an answer to. I am OK at bash and know Java and C but would like to keep this extremely simple. Here is the goal: I log on as root on server A and would like to send a command to servers B C and D via SSH. I want it so that it will automatically log into the servers (with a password) and send a command to them, from server A to the other servers.

So it would go something like this:

- Client logs into server A and runs `send.sh` which will send the commands.

How would I go about doing this in extremely simple bash? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Password authentication is _not_ extremely simple bash. If you want simple, you need to use RSA key or agent authentication.

Comment: Not that I recommend it, but there is the `sshpass` utility.

Comment: Ok I guess I will just use public keys. I have used them in the past I just like password auth more and if it's easier to connect with keys then I will use them.

Answer (score 1):

3 steps :

1. install your [public key](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html) on all 4 machines (a, b, c and d) . If you're using openssh, you need to append your public key to .ssh/authorized_keys (see [OpenSSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)) , if you're using [dropbear](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doku.php?id=oldwiki:dropbearpublickeyauthenticationhowto#why.public.key.authentication%20DropBear) it's a bit different.

   Step 1 is complete when you can log in to *a* , then from *a* to *b*, from *a* to *c*, and from *a* to *d* without any password prompt.
2. Write your `~/send.sh` script on *a* . Since authentication is taken care of, the script is as simple as this:

   ```
   ssh b 'some_command'
   ssh c 'some_other_command'
   ssh d 'yet_another_command'
   ```
3. Run the ssh client from your machine :

   ```
   ssh a '~/send.sh'
   ```

Comment: Yes I'm using openSSH this makes sense to me. So all I would do is just set up the public key in my authorized keys in a and place the key file in what directory. Then I just run the script like ./script.sh (I use putty since I am not dual booting.

Comment: Correct. Once your public key is everywhere, ssh'ing from one machine to another becomes trivial and without prompts, and you can run remote scripts with a simple `ssh machine 'script'`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a file that contains the list of servers the command will ssh to. Simply put one IP address or hostname per line in the file. I'll call it `hosts.txt` here. Then use a while loop to run the command over each connection. Make sure to add your public key to `authorized_keys` on each of the hosts.

```
command="echo test"
while read host
do
    ssh -i [your public key] root@${host} "${command}" < /dev/null
done < hosts.txt
```

If you want to send multiple successive commands to each server, use the "End of Transmission" character as follows (similar to end of file):

```
ssh -o options user@server << EOT
command1
command2
command3
EOT
```

All of the commands in the section surrounded by `EOT` will be run in succession.

Comment: I'd suggest a `</dev/null` on the ssh command to prevent it from eating your stdin.

Comment: Might also add more quotes: `"$command"`; that way if it includes wildcards they're evaluated on the remote end instead of the local end.

Answer (score 0):

Try filling file `call-servers-b-c-and-d.sh` in `a` and execute

```
ssh a ~/call-servers-b-c-and-d.sh
```

`call-servers-b-c-and-d.sh` could contain

```
ssh b command
ssh c command
ssh d command
```

You might also choose to use public key authentication and `ssh-copy-id` to avoid typing passwords.

Comment: Ok so say I am logged into a and I do as you suggested. Can you clarify how I would use the public key or how I could use passwords like 'ssh 1.1.1.1 command (password)' how could I public key otherwise.

Comment: Three commands are enough to use public key authentication: `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-copy-id` and `ssh`. See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/